# Jquery mask add comma last

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask, currency

I am trying to use Jquery Mask

**Html:**

```
<script src="~/Content/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input id="test1" type="text" data-mask-maxlength="false" />
```

**Javascript/Jquery:**

```
$("#test1").mask('000.000.000.000.000.000.000', { reverse: true });
```

**I tried below**

```
 function RemoveRougeChar(convertString) {
            if (convertString.substring(0, 1) == ",") {
                return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)
            }
            return convertString;
        }

        $("#test1").on("focus", function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var num = $this.val().replace(/,/g, "");
            $this.val(num);

        }).on("blur", function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var num = $this.val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '').replace(/,/gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");
            var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(num.replace(/(.{3})/g, "$1,").split("").reverse().join(""));
            $this.val(num2);
        });
```

**Question:**

I have value as below,

```
1

10

100

100.000

1.000.000
```

If user **add comma last of value**  as below

```
1,00

10,0

100,00

100.000,0

1.000.000,00
```

User only add **1 or 2 numbers more** **after comma** after last number like above values.

How can i provide this by using jquery mask

Comment: What about code according to my question if i use digitalbush ?